# spyder4 - hide background variables in variable explorer on Mac?

Tags: python, spyder

[image]

I think that the variable explorer is showing background variables of spyder. How can I hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, those variables can't be hidden anymore. And that's a good thing because it's a reminder that you're importing `pylab` by default in your consoles (which is a bad practice because your code won't be portable outside Spyder).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Carlos Cordoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438386/carlos-cordoba)

I found the option in preferences. **Automatically load Pylab and Numpy Modules** option should be unchecked.

[preference snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6JuX.jpg)